# Unable to scrape string and list at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get `name`, `address` and `key contacts` from a webpage using a python script. I can get them individually in the right way. However, what I wish to do is get the `name` and `address` as string and the key contacts in a list so that I can write them in a csv file in 6 columns. ***I can't find any way to include the value of `data-cfemail` within the list of contacts***.

[Website address](https://www.fis.com/fis/companies/details.asp?l=e&filterby=species&specie_id=615&page=1&company_id=160574&country_id=)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.fis.com/fis/companies/details.asp?l=e&filterby=species&specie_id=615&page=1&company_id=160574&country_id="

res = requests.get(link,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
name = soup.select_one("#name").text.strip()
address = soup.select("#description_details tr:contains('Address:') td")[1].text
contacts = [' '.join(item.get_text(strip=True).split()) for item in soup.select("#contacts table tr td")]
print(name,address,contacts)
```

Current output:

```
Bahia Grande S.A. - BG Group 
MaipÃº 1252 Piso 8Â°
 ['Founder & PresidentMr Guillermo Jacob', 'VP FinanceMr Andres Jacob[email protected]', 'ControllerMr Juan Carlos Peralta[email protected]', 'VP AdmnistrationMs Veronica Vinuela[email protected]', '']
```

Expected output (as the emails are protected the value of `data-cfemail` will do):

```
Bahia Grande S.A. - BG Group 
MaipÃº 1252 Piso 8Â°

[Founder & President, Mr Guillermo Jacob]
[VP Finance, Mr Andres Jacob,bbdad1dad8d4d9fbd9dad3d2dadcc9dad5dfde95d8d4d695dac9]
[Controller,Mr Juan Carlos Peralta,0b61687b6e796a677f6a4b696a63626a6c796a656f6e25686466256a79]
[VP Admnistration,Ms Veronica Vinuela,87f1f1eee9f2e2ebe6c7e5e6efeee6e0f5e6e9e3e2a9e4e8eaa9e6f5]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it the following way restricting to the appropriate tds `#contacts td[height]` then the appropriate ids
`td.select('#contacts_title, #contacts_name, #contacts_email')` then testing in a list comprehension if current has the cfemail and acting accordingly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.fis.com/fis/companies/details.asp?l=e&filterby=species&specie_id=615&page=1&company_id=160574&country_id=')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
name = soup.select_one('#name').text.strip()
address = soup.select_one('#description_details td:contains("Address:") + td div').text

print(name)
print(address)

for td in soup.select('#contacts td[height]'):
    print([i.text.strip().replace('\xa0',' ') if i.select_one('.__cf_email__') is None else i.select_one('.__cf_email__')['data-cfemail']
          for i in td.select('#contacts_title, #contacts_name, #contacts_email')])
```

[image]

---

OP's implementation:

```
contacts = [', '.join([i.text.strip().replace('\xa0',' ') if i.select_one('.__cf_email__') is None else i.select_one('.__cf_email__')['data-cfemail'] for i in td.select('#contacts_title, #contacts_name, #contacts_email')]) for td in soup.select('#contacts td[height]')]
```

Comment: Hi @QHarr, I would be very glad if you take a look at ***[this link](https://pastebin.com/f9rAdzLc)*** to offer any solution. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Hi, sure. Will do this evening.

Comment: It seems I've solved it using this expression `[item.extend([""]) for item in contacts if len(item)<3]` just after the line `contacts`.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `table` storing the contact information:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://www.fis.com/fis/companies/details.asp?l=e&filterby=species&specie_id=615&page=1&company_id=160574&country_id=').text, 'html.parser')
title, address = d.find('div', {'id':'name'}).text, d.find('div', {'id':'description_details'}).tr.div.text
contacts = [[i.find_all('div') for i in b.find_all('td')] for b in d.find('div', {'id':'contacts'}).table.find_all('tr')]
result = [[j.get_text(strip=True) if j.a is None else j.a.span['data-cfemail'] for j in i] for b in contacts for i in b if i]
```

Output:

```
'\xa0Bahia Grande S.A. - BG Group' #title
'MaipÃº 1252 Piso 8Â°' #address
[['Founder & President', 'Mr\xa0Guillermo\xa0Jacob'], ['VP Finance', 'Mr\xa0Andres\xa0Jacob', 'e6878c87858984a684878e8f87819487888283c885898bc88794'], ['Controller', 'Mr\xa0Juan Carlos\xa0Peralta', '264c45564354474a52476644474e4f474154474842430845494b084754'], ['VP Admnistration', 'Ms\xa0Veronica\xa0Vinuela', 'baccccd3d4cfdfd6dbfad8dbd2d3dbddc8dbd4dedf94d9d5d794dbc8']] #contact info
```